# How to create a dictionary with a 3-dimensional key

Tags: c#, dictionary, valuetuple

I need some kind of structure that works like a dictionary, but the key is a 3D point (represented by 3 integers).

```
Ball b1 = new Ball();
Ball b2 = new Ball();

D[-1,3,29] = b1;
D[9,0,3] = b2;
```

I'm thinking about creating something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Ball>>> D = new ...
```

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `ValueTuple` has the appropriate equality and hashcode behavior when used with simple types. As such you can use them (and are suitable) in a dictionary.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<(int,int,int),something>
dict.Add((1,2,3), sometthing);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer since all items within the tuple would function as keys to a dictionary.